# Executing python shell from cmd with subprocess

Tags: python, shell, cmd, subprocess

I want to be able to capture the output of the following command in Python shell:

```
help("modules")
```

This command will give an output to something like this:

```
Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

MySQLdb             argparse            git                 runpy
PIL                 array               gitdb               sched
PyQt5               arrow               glob                secrets
__future__          ast                 greenlet            select
_abc                asynchat            gunicorn            selectors
_ast                asyncio             gzip                setuptools
_asyncio            asyncore            hashlib             shelve
_bisect             atexit              heapq               shlex
_blake2             audioop             hmac                shutil
_bootlocale         base64              html                signal
_bz2                bdb                 http                site
_codecs             binaryornot         idlelib             six
_codecs_cn          binascii            idna                slugify
_codecs_hk          binhex              imaplib             smmap
_codecs_iso2022     bisect              imghdr              smtpd
_codecs_jp          briefcase           imp                 smtplib
_codecs_kr          builtins            importlib           sndhdr
_codecs_tw          bz2                 inspect             socket
_collections        cProfile            io                  socketio
_collections_abc    calendar            ipaddress           socketserver

Enter any module name to get more help.  Or, type "modules spam" to search
for modules whose name or summary contain the string "spam".
```

I wanna be able to run the `python shell` and input `help("modules")` and capture the output. But i can't seem to run the python shell. Here's what i have:

```
import subprocess

def IndexModules():
    command = "python&help(\"modules\")"
    result = subprocess.check_output(command) #Also tried shell=True
    print(result.wait())
```

Does anybody have a working way around this?

Comment: `subprocess.run(['python3', '-c', 'help(object)'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout`. But seems like a strange thing to do since you are already using `python`. May i ask, why you need this ?

Comment: @hansolo I'm trying to capture the output and trim the spaces, basically indexing the modules installed by the user.

Comment: Are you on `linux` ?

Comment: Mmm, i'm on windows.

Comment: There's `pydoc`. `python3 -m pydoc modules` should give you what you need. So the command can be simplified to `subprocess.run(['python3', '-m', 'pydoc', 'modules'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout`

Comment: This is weird. I have python installed with PATH set in environment variables, but it says, `Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640b`

Comment: Windows might have the `py` thing. Try `py -3 -m pydoc modules` and replace as required

Comment: Also, i didn't quite get what "indexing the modules installed by the user." mean ':). The modules installed by the user will be in either `site-packages/` or user site package path. of the respecitive python lib dir

Comment: Trying to see if it works, but is this `pydoc` the same as the `help("modules")` command?

Comment: Yes. That's just showing the document

Comment: @hansolo By "indexing the modules" i mean, the only way (in my knowledge) where i can list the installed modules from the user is through this command or something similar. After capturing the output, it will trim some whitespaces and write it to a file.

Comment: Anyway, hope `pydoc` helps